# gnome-shell-extension not found through apt-cache search

Tags: command-line, apt, gnome-shell-extension

I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux in general), second day of usage, please excuse me for the lack of experience. I'm running 17.04 and I'm trying to set-up an environment to practice and improve my web-development skills. I think it will be useful to have some sort of "control panel for services" such as apache, mysql and be able to turn them on / off easily and monitor their status.

I've found the gnome shell extension which looks similar to what I want, the extension called [Services Systemd](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1034/services-systemd/), and I can see it at my Ubuntu Software Center:

[image]

It has an install button, etc. But since I'm learning to use Ubuntu, I wanted to install it via terminal using "sudo apt-get install" and here I faced a problem unfortunately:

[image]

The same result for both **sudo apt-get install services-systemd** and **sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extension-services-systemd** as well (sure I did "sudo apt-get update" first). So I assumed that maybe the extension has different name and I tried to search for it using **sudo apt-cache search** but seems like I'm missing something, cause I can't find this. Please explain me how am I supposed to install the extensions like this avoiding software centers and other software like "Synaptic".

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just use its install page https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1034/services-systemd/ ?

Comment: @Jos Yes, I want to understand how to use terminal. Cause if I will just use GUI I will never understand the basics. Plus it simply looks irrational for me now, why extension is visible in software center, and not visible via search, while they must provide identical results, right?

Comment: I just looked (quickly) that one is not available via command line, just install it from either software center or the extensions page Jos recommended. There will be PLENTY of other opportunities to use the terminal.